# How to restrict specific Region from shipping?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to restrict some specific regions from the shipping list due to some requirements, so anyone can help here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to restrict some specific region then you can try below method:

vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/ResourceModel/Region/Collection.php  //Added restriction to some states

Please make sure you are override this in your custom module and customize your changes.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, this file having the solution so I think it will solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Let me know if you face any difficulty with this method. Thanks